# memory size of UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, memory-management

I'd like to know the memory size for a `UIImageView` object as I need to show some large image and I need to handle the memory. I guess it is decided by the image property. But I'm not sure how to calculate the actuarial memory size,and below is the code I write to test:

```
    //1.jpg has a size of 4016X2657 and 2.1MB
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"jpg"]];
    NSLog(@"imageData:%d",[imageData length]);
```

The console shows:

```
 imageData:2070461
```

This is exactly the size of 2.1MB.

However, in my opinion the `UIImageView`should know the each pixel to show the image and in other words it should have a memory of :

`4016*2657*4/1024/1024 = 40.7+MB`
 
It is so large and I don't know whether iOS will do some optimization or not.And I also can't find any relevant in the document.

Could anyone help me what is the exactly memory size of a `UIImageView` object?

Comment: @Till, the memory size of a uiimageview object.

Comment: You actually computed it in your question - it is roughly width x height x 4

Comment: That is the raw data for the photo. But I'm not sure whether iOS will do something to optimize it or not in UIImage. Do you know about it?

Comment: It does not optimize the memory usage (use compression) as that would degrade the image quality and / or display performance. The PowerVR (GL/display unit) does support image compression but only a lossy one and that looks horrible in most cases.

Comment: Regarding your flag: if you have a self-answer for your question, post it below, then mark it accepted when the time permits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is described in the question. The memory is the actuarial size of the photo and UIImage will not do optimization.